# How to recursively scan all folders and files with nodejs on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, fs

I know I can ennumerate all subfolders of a folder in nodejs using `fs.readder()`

On *nix I can just start with the root path `/`

But on Windows each drive has its own root such as `C:\`, `D:\`, etc and does not have an overall root.

But I can't seem to find anything that comes with nodejs to give me a list of drives, or anything that acts like a root of all drives under Windows.

Am I missing something or is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: The Windows API is layered ove the NT API. NT's root directory is in the object namespace, since almost everything is an object in NT, as opposed to everything being a file in Unix. Device objects already act as mountpoints in NT (e.g. "\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows"), but we usually use volume GUID and drive-letter mountpoints that are implemented as object symlinks in the "\??" local-device directory (a merged local logon and global view). In the NT API, we could walk the object tree and try to query the root file listing, if any, on each device object.

Comment: The above implementation details are hidden from the Windows API. Instead we would use `FindFirstVolumeW` and `FindNextVolumeW`, which enumerates each volume device that was registered with the mountpoint manager and assigned a volume GUID mountpoint. Try to map it back to a drive-letter via `GetVolumePathNamesForVolumeNameW`. Then call `GetLogicalDrives` to find mapped drives and legacy drives, which aren't registered with the mountpoint manager. This gives us a list of "\\?\[A-Z]:" and "\\?\Volume{GUID}" mountpoints. Does node.js provide an FFI facility to call WINAPI functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a method in the built-in modules to list all the drives. The best approach is to use a package to handle all the different OS logic.

You can use [drivelist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/drivelist) for that. Where you will get a list of all drives, and then you can call `fs.readdir`